# numpy matmul very slow when one of the two is np.array(dtype=np.complex128).real

Tags: python, numpy

I discovered that when `matmul`ing two `numpy` arrays, if one of the two is the real or imaginary part of a bigger complex array, the operation can be tens, or even hundreds, time slower than using the original complex array.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

class timeit():
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def __enter__(self):
        self.t0 = time()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print(f'{self.string} : {time() - self.t0}')


A  = np.random.rand(200, 1000) + 0j
B = np.random.rand(1000, 5000)

with timeit('with complex'):
    out = A @ B

Ar = A.real
with timeit('after .real'):
    out = Ar @ B

Ai = (A * 1j).imag
with timeit('after .imag'):
    out = Ai @ B

with timeit('after .astype(float)'):
    out = A.astype(np.float64()) @ B

with timeit('after .real.astype(float)'):
    out = A.real.astype(np.float64()) @ B
```

The output is

```
with complex : 0.09374785423278809
after .real : 1.9792003631591797
after .imag : 1.717487096786499
after .astype(float) : 0.016920804977416992
after .real.astype(float) : 0.017952442169189453
```

Note how when one of the two arrays is `A.real` or `A.imag` the operation is 20 times slower (the number can go up to hundreds of time slower if the arrays are bigger).

Using `A.astype(np.float64)` is very fast, but it throw a warning every time, even if the imaginary part is null.

The only fast and quiet solution seems to be `A.real.astype(float)`, but, to be honest, it looks quite ugly to me.

Checking the memory address of these array I obtain the following

```
def aid(x):
    # This function returns the memory
    # block address of an array.
    return x.__array_interface__['data'][0]

print(f'ID(A.real) == ID(A): {aid(A.real) == aid(A)}')
print(f'ID(A.imag) == ID(A): {aid(A.imag) == aid(A)}')
print(f'ID(A.astype) == ID(A): {aid(A.astype(np.float64())) == aid(A)}')
print(f'ID(A.real.astype) == ID(A): {aid(A.real.astype(np.float64())) == aid(A)}')
```

this returns

```
ID(A.real) == ID(A): True
ID(A.imag) == ID(A): False
ID(A.astype) == ID(A): False
ID(A.real.astype) == ID(A): False
```

This seems to indicate that `A.real` has the same memory address as `A`, while `A.astype(np.float64)` does not. Could this be causing this behavior? However `A` and `A.imag` have different memory addresses, but still the `matmul` is very slow.

Is this a bug?
Is the solution with `A.real.astype(np.float64)` the one I should use?

Comment: Or perhaps pickle is incorrectly throwing away most of your data.

Comment: Can't reproduce that on my system. both give roughly 0.2s for me as expected.

Comment: @mCoding check the edit. Also `numpy.array.copy()` solves the problem. This has nothing to do with `pickle` in my opinion

Comment: Without knowing how the orignal arrays were created I don't think we can help.  I can't think of an array storage or property that would slow things down and not also pass through `pickle` or `copy`.

Comment: @hpaulj that was basically my question. Which property could be causing this and not passing through `pickle` or `copy`? Or... which property should I check in the original array that would allow me to reproduce the error? I will try to produce a minimal working example, but the problem seems hard to reproduce (even if it happens systematically in my code)

Comment: GOT IT! I've been able to reproduce the error. I'm basically re-writing the question from scratches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not memory location or layout that matters.  It's the route that `@` chooses depending on the type of input.  `A.real` is not a "new" array; it's a method of accessing the real values of the complex dtype.  I don't have time to present my full timing results but here a couple of quick results

```
In [2]: timeit A@B
436 ms ± 32.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

adding the `real` slows this way down:

```
In [3]: timeit A.real@B
3.93 s ± 4.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [4]: %%timeit a = A.real
   ...: a@B
3.92 s ± 3.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But making a new float array speeds things up:

```
In [5]: %%timeit a = A.real.copy()
   ...: a@B 
101 ms ± 496 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`A.real` does not actual do any calculations:

```
In [6]: timeit A.real    
203 ns ± 9.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And making a new array from the real values isn't that slow:

```
In [7]: timeit A.real.copy()
239 µs ± 3.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Including the copy inline doesn't hurt time:

```
In [8]: timeit A.real.copy()@B
102 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`dot` isn't bothered by the `real`:

```
In [9]: timeit A.real.dot(B)
106 ms ± 3.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`A.dot(B)` times the same as `A@B`.

So complex evaluation is about 4x slower to float.  Given that `A` has twice as mean values, that's sounds reasonable.

`dot` handles the `real` correctly, extracting the real values without much fuss.

`@` has some sort of bug, sending it off on a slow track.

Comment: So you think this is due to a bug in the implementation of `@`? In the previous version of the question I did notice that `.copy()` solves the problem. My question was… why?

Comment: `matmul` apparently chooses different evaluation routes depending on the nature of the inputs.  For straight forward evaluation of float arrays it passes the task directly to highly optimized BLAS type routines.  But it's compiled code, so it's harder to explore.  There may be some discussion(s) on the github repositiory.