# Numpy `matmul` performs ~100 times worse than `dot` on array views

Tags: python, numpy, performance

It was brought to my attention that the `matmul` function in numpy is performing significantly worse than the `dot` function when multiplying array views. In this case my array view is the real part of a complex array. Here is some code which reproduces the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit
N = 1300
xx = np.random.randn(N, N) + 1j
yy = np.random.randn(N, N) + 1J

x = np.real(xx)
y = np.real(yy)
assert np.shares_memory(x, xx)
assert np.shares_memory(y, yy)

dot = timeit('np.dot(x,y)', number = 10, globals = globals())
matmul = timeit('np.matmul(x,y)', number = 10, globals = globals())

print('time for np.matmul: ', matmul)
print('time for np.dot: ', dot)
```

On my machine the output is as follows:

```
time for np.matmul:  23.023062199994456
time for np.dot:  0.2706864000065252
```

This clearly has something to do with the shared memory as replacing `np.real(xx)` with `np.real(xx).copy()` makes the performance discrepancy go away.

Trolling the numpy docs was not particularly helpful as the listed differences did not discuss implementation details when dealing with memory views.

Comment: A possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914877/numpy-matmul-very-slow-when-one-of-the-two-is-np-arraydtype-np-complex128-real.  I won't flag it as duplicate yet, incase someone else can add a more definitive explanation.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/23123

Comment: @hpaulj Yep, looks like a duplicate except the other question focuses on a specific data type. I can reproduce the issue with regular floats and array views such as `[::2,::2]`. As mentioned in the github issue linked by @Chrysophylaxs this seems to be a bug with non-contiguous arrays.

Comment: My timings suggest that `dot` routinely uses `copy` when the inputs can't be sent directly to BLAS.  `matmul` uses some slower calculation method.

Comment: BLAS type code can only handle contiguous data for a limited number of dtypes.  `numpy` developers have to choose between massaging other arrays in a compatible form, or use other code - which won't be so fast.

Comment: I submitted a [github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/23588) on the topic. I think we learned all we could here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These timings indicate the `dot` is doing a `copy` with `real`:

```
In [22]: timeit np.dot(xx.real,xx.real)
232 ms ± 3.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: timeit np.dot(xx.real.copy(),xx.real.copy())
232 ms ± 4.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Applying that to `matmul` produces nearly the same times:

```
In [24]: timeit np.matmul(xx.real.copy(),xx.real.copy())
231 ms ± 3.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Again, `matmul` with `real` is taking some slow route.  `matmul/dot` both do poorer when given `int` arrays, though not as slow as the `matmul real` case.  `matmul/dot` can also handle `object` dtypes, but that's even slower.

So there's a lot going on under the covers that we, as python level users, don't see (and isn't documented).

### edit

I was tempted to change the title to focus on complex-real, but decided to check another `view` - a slice of a float array

```
In [42]: y=xx.real.copy()[::2,::2];y.shape,y.dtype
Out[42]: ((650, 650), dtype('float64'))

In [43]: timeit np.dot(y,y)
36.4 ms ± 63.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [44]: timeit np.dot(y.copy(),y.copy())
35.6 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Again it is evident that `dot` is using `copies` of the view.  `matmul` does not:

```
In [45]: timeit np.matmul(y,y)
1.89 s ± 3.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

but with copies the times are the same as dot:

```
In [46]: timeit np.matmul(y.copy(),y.copy())
35.3 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So my guess is that `dot` routinely makes a `copy` if it can't send the arrays directly to the BLAS routines.  `matmul` apparently takes a slower route instead.

### edit

While their handling of 2d arrays is similar, `dot` and `matmul` are quite different in how they handle 3+d arrays.  In fact the main reason to add `@` was to provide a convenient 'batch' notion to matrix multiplication.

Sticking with the large complex arrays, lets make one 3x larger:

```
In [49]: yy=np.array([xx,xx,xx]);yy.shape
Out[49]: (3, 1300, 1300)

In [50]: timeit np.dot(xx,xx)
794 ms ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)    
In [51]: timeit np.dot(xx,yy)       # (yy,xx) same timings
55.5 s ± 151 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [52]: timeit np.matmul(xx,yy)    # (yy,yy) same
2.58 s ± 362 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`matmul` has just increased the time by 3; `dot` by 70.  I could explore things more, but not with timings in the minute range.

Comment: Looks like [matmul](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3480b5fa457f5b1aecd7f2f364427dee393497cc/numpy/core/src/umath/matmul.c.src#L217) defaults to a dumb O(n^3) implementation with no regards for CPU cache if it decides that BLAS can not do the computation. I guess this explains why there is such a large performance gap with big arrays.

Indeed, looks like dot is doing a copy to pass the array to BLAS instead. Everything seems consistent.

The only question remains... Why is this not documented anywhere and requires reading source code?